# Still can't see why $\nabla \times \mathbf J(\mathbf r') = 0$ in Biot-Savart derivation

Tags: vector-fields, magnetostatics

When deriving the differential form of Biot-Savart's law (which is also Ampere's law under magnetostatic conditions) there is one step which I am still not fully convinced.

We will firstly use this image for reference:
[image]

In this case the current density exists where the circle/sphere is located ($\mathbf r'$) and we wish to know the magnetic field at the point $\mathbf r$.

Applying Biot-Savart we get $ \mathbf {B}(\mathbf r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac{\mathbf J(\mathbf r') \times (\mathbf r - \mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|^3} dV' $ where we integrate over the current source, hence why the primed coordinates are used.

Expanding the expression we arrive at $ \mathbf {B}(\mathbf r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac{\mathbf J(\mathbf r') \times (\mathbf r - \mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|^3} dV' = \nabla \times\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac{\mathbf J(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}dV' - \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac{\nabla \times \mathbf J(\mathbf r') } {|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} dV' $

It is stated that since the current density is a function of the primed coordinates and not of the unprimed then its curl (with respect to the unprimed) must be null, i.e, $\nabla \times \mathbf J(\mathbf r') = 0$ then the expression is reduced to $ \mathbf {B}(\mathbf r) = \nabla \times\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int \frac{\mathbf J(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}dV' $.

It isn't clear to me is how this can be the case, it seems it is assumed that $r'$ is indepedant of $r$, however the current density is defined over all $r$, it is simply just evaluated at $r'$ as this is where it is non zero. As such, the curl cannot be zero. If anyone can give me an explanation I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: The value of $J$ at the point $r'$ is not affected by a change in  the place (i.e $r$) at which  you are evaluating $B$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate $r'$ represents the *position of the current source*. The coordinate $r$ represents *the position of the observer*. Logically speaking, it is possible to move the observer without moving the current source. It is also possible to move the current source without moving the observer. Therefore, $r$ and $r'$ are independent coordinates.

Even though both $r$ and $r'$ span "all of space", they refer to the position of different, independent entities. That is why they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

With the curl operator, $\nabla \times$, is a combination of partial derivatives. It is important to remember what the partial derivatives are with respect to. In this case, the partial derivatives are with respect to $\mathbf{r}$, not $\mathbf{r'}$. So $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})$ is a constant with respect to $\mathbf{r}$. Meaning $$\nabla \times \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})=\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'}) (\nabla \times 1) = 0$$

If that is not convincing then you can always just expand with $$\mathbf r = x \ \mathbf{\hat i} + y \ \mathbf{\hat j} + z \ \mathbf{\hat k}$$ $$\mathbf {r'} = x' \ \mathbf{\hat i} + y' \ \mathbf{\hat j} + z' \ \mathbf{\hat k}$$ $$\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})= J_x (x',y',z') \ \mathbf{\hat i}+ J_y (x',y',z') \ \mathbf{\hat j}+ J_z (x',y',z') \ \mathbf{\hat k}$$ Then we can write $$\nabla \times \mathbf J (\mathbf{r'})= 
\left(\frac{\partial J_z(x',y',z')}{\partial y} -\frac{\partial J_y(x',y',z')}{\partial z}\right)\mathbf{\hat i} + 
\left(\frac{\partial J_x(x',y',z')}{\partial z} -\frac{\partial J_z(x',y',z')}{\partial x}\right)\mathbf{\hat j} + 
\left(\frac{\partial J_y(x',y',z')}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial J_x(x',y',z')}{\partial y}\right)\mathbf{\hat k}$$ Now, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}J_z(x',y',z')=0$ because $J_z(x',y',z')$ is not a function of $y$. Similarly with all of the other terms in that expression. So therefore we get $$\nabla \times \mathbf{ J} (\mathbf{r'})=0$$

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, my question referred to the reason why the primed coordinates are independent of the unprimed, in other words, why $r'$ is not a function of $r$. Of course, if it is already proven that they are in fact independent then the curl must be zero as you have shown.

Comment: @rr1303 I explained exactly that in the first sentence of the last paragraph.